# Python regex match multiline block of text

Tags: python, regex

I wrote an  regex to select the first block, but it doesn't work.
It just select `i2.2.2.0` and when I want to add another string it doesn't have any

My input is:

```
> 1.1.1.0/24       0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i
* i2.2.2.0/24       2.2.2.2                  0    100      0 i
*>i                 123.2.2.106              0    100      0 i
*>i                 123.1.1.106              0    100      0 i
* i3.3.3.0/24       123.3.3.107              0    100      0 i
* i                 123.3.3.107              0    100      0 i
* i123.1.1.0/24     2.2.2.2                  0    100      0 i
* i                 123.2.2.106              0    100      0 i
*>                  0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i
* i123.2.2.0/24     2.2.2.2                  0    100      0 i
* i                 123.2.2.106              0    100      0 i
*>                  0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i
* i123.3.3.0/24     2.2.2.2                  0    100      0 i
*>i                 123.2.2.106              0    100      0 i
*>i                 123.1.1.106              0    100      0 i
```

my results should be:

1. `* i2.2.2.0/24       2.2.2.2                  0    100      0 i
   *>i                 123.2.2.106              0    100      0 i
   *>i                 123.1.1.106`
2. `i123.3.3.0/24     2.2.2.2                  0    100      0 i
    *>i                 123.2.2.106              0    100      0 i
    *>i                 123.1.1.106`
   result.

my regex is:
`(i2.2.2.0/24).*(\n123.2.2.106)...`

I need the expression to use in python code. I searched a lot but Ican't find the result.

Thanks :)

Comment: Try this `^[*> ]+i([\d./]+)?\s+([\d.]+)\s+(.*)`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I test your regex, the result is all lines but I want to match first number one (the three line I wrote in my post at result section). Then it find the second one.

Comment: You provided current output and expected results, but what is the input?

Comment: @stribizhev, Sorry, I edit my post.

Comment: You don't mention what flags you use to compile the regex. You need at least `re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL`

Comment: Now, I wrote this expression: **(i2.2.2.0\/24.[ ]{2,}2.2.2.2.+\n\*>i[ ]{2,}123.2.2.106.*\n\*>i[ ]{2,}123.1.1.106)** and it works! But in this expression the sequence of input should be considered and this is wrong because sequence of inputs mybe different every time I run the script.

Comment: @F.M: [Are you sure](https://regex101.com/r/dT7rN3/1)? You did not post the specifications: what should be static, what can be at the beginning, what can be the end boundary... If it works - great, but the post is still very unclear.

Comment: @stribizhev: I'm sorry, this is because of my bad english! This input is a output of a _cisco router_ (BGP service) and every time some section maybe different in sequence, For example:** i2.2.2.0\/24** is always in it's place, but 2.2.2.2,123.2.2.106 , 123.1.1.106 may displaced their location, I mean after i2.2.2.0/24 first 123.2.2.106 comes or 123.1.1.106! Thanks a lot Stribizhev to put your time for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You want to match blocks belonging to selected network addresses. The continuation lines are recognizable by space in place of an address. The regular expression

```
(\* i(?:123.3.3.0/24|2.2.2.0/24).+\n(?:\*.i .+\n)*)
```

for example matches (with the *global* modifier) both the `2.2.2.0/24` and the `123.3.3.0/24` block in any order; see [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oR7jL3/1).